# Add Constraint to Table column when using Create.Table, FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, t-sql, fluent-migrator

I am using FluentMigrator to create a new table in DB. After I created, i realized that I need to add a constraint like the following in T-Sql:

Assume I already have a table tableA

```
      Alter Table tableA
      Add Constraint ConstraintA CHECK(([ColA]>=(0) AND [ColA]<(100)))
```

How do I create the constraint using FluentMigrator in .Net? I have googled and did not find any answer. Thanks!

Comment: Much better answers here: [Is it possible to add CHECK constraint with fluent API in EF7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245449/is-it-possible-to-add-check-constraint-with-fluent-api-in-ef7)

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254423/1048432   https://stackoverflow.com/a/59895079/1048432

Answer (score 24):

This is a more idiomatic way of doing it in FluentMigrator

```
Create.UniqueConstraint("SalesIdAndUsername")
  .OnTable("users")
  .Columns("username", "SalesId");
```

Comment: That's all well and good for a UNIQUE constraint, but the question is in regards to a CHECK constraint.

Comment: Even though it didn't address the original question directly, it was exactly what I was looking for (the question title does not discriminate about which type of constraint is wanted).  I wish people would be more thoughtful about using the downvote option.  A simple non-vote is way more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @JamesWilson well, I could also answer "42", and I can assure you that it's an answer to a very important question. Still, it doesn't answer to this. Just jocking, but I was trying to use this answer to create a `CHECK` constraint, which this answer does not provide. The other answer by Castrohenge is not pretty, but it's correct.

Answer (score 8):

You could execute the raw SQL using the Execute.Sql method within your migration. Eg:

```
Execute.Sql("ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintA CHECK(([ColA]>=(0) AND [ColA]<(100)))");
```