# Is it possible to add CHECK constraint with fluent API in EF7?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to add CHECK constraint with fluent API in Entity Framework 7?

I need to acheive something like this:

```
...
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn CHECK (SomeColumn >= X);
```

It is ok if solution is provider-specific - I am targeting MsSqlServer only (at least now).

Comment: It is not check constraint, but I have used the following to enforce only blessed values:
    `public sealed class ProfileStatus
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public static readonly ProfileStatus Public = new ProfileStatus("Public");
        public static readonly ProfileStatus Private = new ProfileStatus("Private");
        public static readonly ProfileStatus VerifiedOnly = new ProfileStatus("VerifiedOnly");

        private ProfileStatus(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
}`

And I can not get it the format correctly, sorry...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of EF 7.0.0-rc1, it isn't possible with the fluent API.

You can define the constraint  manually in the migration

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn CHECK (SomeColumn >= X);");
```

Answer (score 22):

EF Core 7.0 +

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<SomeTable>()
        .ToTable(table => table.HasCheckConstraint("CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn", "[SomeColumn] >= X"));
}
```

EF Core 3.0 - 6.0

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeTable>(entity =>
        entity.HasCheckConstraint("CK_SomeTable_SomeColumn", "[SomeColumn] >= X");
}
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering you need to install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` NuGet package to use this extension method.

Comment: I installed that package but I can't find the right `using` path...

Comment: This has become obsolete. New syntax is ```modelBuilder.Entity<SomeTable>(entity => entity.ToTable(tbl => tbl.HasCheckConstraint(...)));```.

Comment: @H.deJonge thanks for the tip, updated :)

Answer (score 1):

`Lukas Kabrt` is still valid in 2019 so I had to create a special migration that I will include constraint and its drop:

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
alter table AdminObjectReview add CONSTRAINT CK_AdminObjectReview_OnlyOneType CHECK 
( 
      (CASE WHEN AnswerId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    + (CASE WHEN QuestionId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    + (CASE WHEN CommentId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    + (CASE WHEN UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    + (CASE WHEN TagId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
     = 1 )
");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql("alter table AdminObjectReview  drop CONSTRAINT CK_AdminObjectReview_OnlyOneType");
        }
```

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything beyond what that the accepted answer already explains. Can you make that clearer?

Comment: It does. Extends the accepted answer with a suggestion, that the constraint can / should be dropped in the migrations Down method. +1 because the -1 was unfair