# How to make a composite primary key bidirectional?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-5

My problem is in the title. I want to make a composite primary key as bidirectional. What I mean by bidrectional? Let me explain:

I have a friendship table. Primary keys are: **SenderId and ReceiverId**

In OnModelCreating:

```
builder.Entity<Friendship>()
                .HasKey(i => new { i.SenderId, i.ReceiverId });
```

So my friendship entities have primary keys like *{SenderId, ReceiverId}*. But not like *{ReceiverId, SenderId}*. I want to make keys to be both ways. In this way, my friendship requests will be unique and I will not create duplicate friendship requests as follows:

[image: Friendship Table]

Is this possible?

NOTE: I know how to check if there is a entry with those IDs.But I want to implement the database to reject the new entry with the same IDs in both ways.

Comment: In your case  you  just don't need to repeate the keys the second time.  One pair will be plenty

Comment: @Serge This is what OP wants to prevent at database level, i.e. to **not allow** records with let say (1, 2) and (2, 1) keys

Answer (score 2):

You need a key that conforms to a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form), i.e. always appear in the same order.

For example, instead of having a `ReceiverID` and a `SenderID`, you'd have two neutrally named fields (e.g. `ParticipantA` and `ParticipantB`) plus a constraint that `ParticipantA` must be less than `ParticipantB`. This way, you can set a constraint so that each pairing of IDs can only appear once, regardless of who is sending and who is receiving.

You'd then need to add a column that specifies direction of the relationship, e.g. who is the sender or if it is bidirectional.

Thus instead of

```
SenderID   ReceiverID
--------   ----------
1111       2222
4444       3333
1234       5678
5678       1234
```

You'd have

```
ParticipantA   ParticipantB  Sender
------------   ------------  ---------
1111           2222          A
3333           4444          B
1234           5678          BIDIRECTIONAL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to have a database control that throws a error while entering duplicate entry, instead of having a new column that controls if it is duplicate or not.

Comment: You misunderstand. There is no column that controls if it's a duplicate or not. There is a constraint that prevents duplicates. Because duplicates are no longer allowed, you need a column that tells you directionality.

Comment: Oh okay, could you tell me how can I write that constraint with fluent API? @JohnWu

Comment: @Huntow [Apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245449/is-it-possible-to-add-check-constraint-with-fluent-api-in-ef7) in pure fluent, you need to code the SQL `ALTER TABLE Friendship ADD CONSTRAINT Friendship_Id_Order CHECK (ParticipantA < ParticipantB)`

Answer (score 2):

As @John Wu points out, you need a composite key where the containing key values are always in order, so (1, 2) and (2, 1) are both mapped to (1, 2), thus treated as equal.

However the proposed implementation requires too much changes to the database model and how you work with it. Also prevents having natural `User.Senders` and `User.Receivers` collection navigation properties if needed to obtain such information for a `User`.

So instead of modifying the existing primary data model, what you need is unique constraint (index) on a "normalized" composite key `(User1Id, User2Id)`, where (in preudo code) `User1Id = Min(SenderId, ReceiverId)` and `User2Id = Max(SenderId, ReceiverId)`.

The implementation of this is database specific. For SqlServer it can be implemented by creating two computed columns and then create unique constraint (index) on them, e.g.

```
// the two shadow properties mapped to the computed columns
modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
    .Property<Guid>("UserId1")
    .HasComputedColumnSql("case when SenderId < ReceiverId then SenderId else ReceiverId end");

modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
    .Property<Guid>("UserId2")
    .HasComputedColumnSql("case when SenderId < ReceiverId then ReceiverId else SenderId end");

// the unique index using them
modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
    .HasIndex("UserId1", "UserId2")
    .IsUnique();
```

Comment: Nice approach! Just one addition: I would make the computed columns persisted (stored = true).

Comment: Hi @Gert, wouldn't it be redundant since the computed values have to be stored in the index anyway? I'm not sure, just asking.

Comment: Depends a bit on how the columns are going to be used. If it's *just* for the unique index it may be redundant. Actually, it's a broad subject, but I like to persist computed columns to give Sql Server the chance to skip re-evaluation, which, nevertheless, it won't always do.